# Create command line variables with PATH

Tags: command-line, variable

As I am more of a web guy, i need a little help with this one, so I will explain what I am trying to do before I ask.

I am creating batch script that will:

- GET request from an external server (json file), receive data, save locally as .json
- Use JQ to navigate the json for **result[0].title**
- Use the 'title' as a parameter for a curl request

Once I have the file locally. I would use JQ to find the data in the object

`cat file.json | jq '.results[0].title' > $1 &&`
`curl -i -H "Accept: application/html" -H "Content-Type: application/html" -X GET http://example.com/test/$1 > test.txt`

Is is possible to set local variables in command line '$1' for temporary use in a piped command?

Am I waaay off here?

Comment: v=$(jq ... file.json) && curl ... /$v ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `$1` typically has a special meaning (the first parameter passed to a script/function/etc.) you can indeed save the output of commands in variables.

```
title=$(jq -r '.results[0].title' file.json)
curl -i -H "Accept: application/html" -H "Content-Type: application/html" -X GET http://example.com/test/"$title" > test.txt
```

The first part runs the commands `jq -r '.results[0].title' file.json` and save the output (whatever shows up on `stdout` into the variable `title`.  Then we run the `curl` command and expand the `title` variable as part of the URL.